# Linking error while using FFTW as backend for the Eigen FFT implementation

Tags: c++, fft, eigen3, fftw

I'm currently attempting to use FFTW as the backend for Eigen's FFT implementation, which is located in the unsupported section of Eigen. However, I've encountered a compilation error due to linker issues.

In a nutshell, my project has the following directory structure:

```
project_root
│   CMakeLists.txt
└───src
│   └───ccs
│       │   CMakeLists.txt
│       │   LDPCDecoder.h
│       │   LDPCDecoder.cpp
└───thirdparty
    └───fftw
        └───...
```

I'm utilizing Eigen's FFT in LDPCDecoder.cpp.

During compilation, I'm encountering numerous "undefined reference" errors like the following:

```
[build] LDPC_decoder.cpp:(.text+0x8fa0): undefined reference to `fftwf_execute_dft_r2c'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: LDPC_decoder.cpp:(.text+0x93b1): undefined reference to                fftwf_execute_dft_c2r'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: LDPC_decoder.cpp:(.text+0x9a28): undefined reference to fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: LDPC_decoder.cpp:(.text+0x9d7e): undefined reference to fftwf_plan_dft_c2r_1d'
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

I've installed the FFTW library in the thirdparty/fftw directory using the following steps:

```
./configure --prefix <PathTofftwDirectory>
make
make install
```

As a result, I now have 'libfftw3.a' located in 'thirdparty/fftw/lib/libfftw3.a.'

Here's the content of the CMakeLists.txt file in the ccs directory:

```
add_library(ccs
    tree_decoder.cpp
    tree_decoder.h
    tree_encoder.cpp
    tree_encoder.h
    treecode_generation.h
    treecode_generation.cpp
    ccs_encoder.h
    ccs_decoder.h
    SPARCS_encoder.h
    SPARCS_encoder.cpp
    SPARCS_decoder.h
    SPARCS_decoder.cpp
    tree_encoder_BPSPARCS.h
    tree_encoder_BPSPARCS.cpp
    BPSPARCS_encoder.h
    BPSPARCS_encoder.cpp
    BPSPARCS_decoder.h
    BPSPARCS_decoder.cpp
    LDPC_decoder.h
    LDPC_decoder.cpp
    tree_decoder_BPSPARCS.h
    tree_decoder_BPSPARCS.cpp
    tree_decoder_triadicGraph.h
    tree_decoder_triadicGraph.cpp
    BPSPARCS_codingParameters.h
    BPSPARCS_codingParameters.cpp
)

target_include_directories(ccs
    PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/aff3ct
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/fftw/include
)

link_directories(ccs ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/fftw/lib)

target_link_libraries(ccs
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/fftw/lib/libfftw3.a
    aff3ct-static-lib
)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve these linker errors?

I tried to link the library againts the toplevel executable instead ob the static lib ccs, but this did not fix the error. I also did a clean rebuild of the project and a rebuild of the fftw3lib.a

Comment: `libfftw3` is the version for `double` precision. If you want `float`, you have to link against `libfftw3f`. You see it in the function name. It starts with `fftwf_` instead of `fftw_`